# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Wi-Fi Frequent Disconnection

Tags: wireless, atheros, 22.04

I have a fairly old dell laptop. It used to work fine till 20.04 LTS. After moving 22.04, I started to experience problems with Wi-Fi connection. Sometimes no network, slow speed, if I disconnect and re-connect, it works for about 30 seconds, then suddenly Wi-Fi signal shows weak, then drops the connection. Is it hardware or software related? Any help is much appreciated.

`lspci -nnk |grep -i Wireless`

`02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01) Subsystem: Dell QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [1028:020c]`

Kernel
`Linux 5.15.0-27-generic x86_64`