# Wifi suddenly drops on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04

I did a fresh clean install of Ubuntu 22.04 and I am very new to Ubuntu/Linux Kernel. As a result the wifi on my system connects but keeps dropping even though I am sitting 6 feet across from the router. I have it installed on on my HP 15-db1xxx, when I boot up my system.  [Wifi on startup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtoWG.png)
, the wifi signals initially are healthy but after 4-5 minutes [Wifi signals after usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRI4Z.png) . The signal fluctuation happens when I am using the internet and I loose the connection, for instance, the pages will stop loading and I have keep hitting the refresh button until it starts working. This has become really annoying and has been blocking me at work. I have not encountered this problem with Windows 10 which is dual-booted alongside Ubuntu 22.04.

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: 00:68:eb:7c:74:81
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.15.0-30-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:40 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c0904000-c0904fff memory:c0900000-c0903fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: c0:e4:34:57:65:97
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8821ce driverversion=5.15.0-30-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.20 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:73 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c0800000-c080ffff
```

Here is the PCI information about my computer

```
sudo lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 PCIe GPP Bridge [6:0]
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 PCIe GPP Bridge [6:0]
00:01.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 PCIe GPP Bridge [6:0]
00:01.5 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 PCIe GPP Bridge [6:0]
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus A
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 61)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 7
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Silicon Motion, Inc. SM2263EN/SM2263XT SSD Controller (rev 03)
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso/Raven 2 [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] (rev c2)
05:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio Controller
05:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
05:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven USB 3.1
05:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven USB 3.1
05:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor
05:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
05:00.7 Non-VGA unclassified device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/Renoir Non-Sensor Fusion Hub KMDF driver
```

Here is the laptop information that might help:

```
sudo lshw -C system
salman-ryzen                
    description: Notebook
    product: HP Laptop 15-db1xxx (8LX89PA#ABJ)
    vendor: HP
    version: Type1ProductConfigId
    serial: CND9461SXT
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.1.1 dmi-3.1.1 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=103C_5335KV HP Notebook sku=8LX89PA#ABJ uuid=64de2ba6-0a01-ea11-8102-0068eb7c7481
  *-pnp00:00
       product: PnP device PNP0c02
       physical id: 0
       capabilities: pnp
       configuration: driver=system
  *-pnp00:01
       product: PnP device PNP0b00
       physical id: 1
       capabilities: pnp
       configuration: driver=rtc_cmos
  *-pnp00:04
       product: PnP device PNP0c02
       physical id: 4
       capabilities: pnp
       configuration: driver=system
  *-pnp00:05
       product: PnP device PNP0c01
       physical id: 5
       capabilities: pnp
       configuration: driver=system
```

This problem is driving me insane and disturbing the workflow. This problem never occurs on Windows 10. I have tried cloning https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce for the Wifi driver and installed it, but this did not work either.

I have also tried these solutions
[Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Wi-Fi Frequent Disconnection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405908/ubuntu-22-04-lts-wi-fi-frequent-disconnection)
[WiFi randomly disconnected on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030653/wifi-randomly-disconnected-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts)

And they have not worked for me. Please help!

EDIT: So I uninstalled Ubuntu 22.04 and did a clean install of MX-Linux 21 with Kernel 5.10-14, and the wifi is working flawlessly. That problem has long gone but I think we will have to report this bug on the newer kernels. I tried updating kernels on Ubuntu form 5.15 to 5.17, but no luck! Anyways, I think Ubuntu 22.04 is still fairly new and Canonical is working on fixing the bugs. Thanks for the help guys, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not your imagination. Many of us have the same issue. See this post:

[Wifi disconnects intermittently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403773/22-04-wifi-keeps-disconnecting-for-a-few-seconds-frequently)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that older kernels did not have a driver for this wifi card at all, while newer kernels (5.15+) have a built-in driver that isn't very good. Therefore, if you tried to install your own, better driver, it would conflict with the built-in one and cause even more problems.

The solution is to blacklist the built-in driver from the newer kernels, and install your own. See the steps [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401475/why-rtl8821ce-or-wifi-is-removed-during-kernel-update-on-20-04-4-lts)

Comment: I am running MX-Linux with 5.10 kernel. It is working fine and never skips a beat. Thanks for the help though! Will try installing Ubuntu and try your solution.